# Store a constant value and append in CSS property in CSS file

Tags: css

Is it possible to store a constant value and append in CSS property in CSS file ?

For example

CSS

```
.test {
    background:url('img/test.gif');
 }
```

Is there anything where we append a path in CSS.

It's only my guess

```
content= 'files/images/';

    background:url('img/test.gif');
```

to

```
    background:url(content'/img/test.gif');
```

So that, it will output as

```
    background:url('files/images/img/test.gif');
```

It's only for knowledge, whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: Not in standard CSS, as far as I know. You can do this, and far cooler things if you use something like LESS (http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: @xbonez: correct, pop that in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in standard CSS, as far as I know. You can do this, and far cooler things, if you use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Some examples of 'far cooler things' are defining functions/methods, and evaluating mathematical expressions etc. Standard CSS does not allow any such tomfoolery.

Comment: He's only trying to get his URLs right, LESS is cool and all but thats not really his problem here. He asks for variables but needs a way to fix his urls.

Comment: He's not looking for a way to "fix" his urls. He's looking to "store a constant value". This is only possible using dynamic CSS generators such as LESS.

Comment: @sg3s: I want to give a `content` as variable. In development phase, I only needs `content = ''` and in production phase needs `content ='files/images/'` . I want to give `content` in some urls in css file. If variable is possible, I only need to change `content` value on shifting from development to production, otherwise I want to do manually change all urls before change to production phase.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "base" tag to do that.

Comment: An example would be nice, nonetheless probably an excellent solution to this particular problem.

Comment: @James Alarie: `<base>` tag will change all url in a document. I only need certain urls.